# How to get correct week number in Access

Tags: ms-access

I get a large data set every week, with Start Date and End Date, Start Date is always Monday and End Date is always Sunday. I want to be able to do a rolling YTD on Sales for different products by week. I am trying to give each week's data a week number. But my first week is 12/28/2015-1/3/2016, it keeps giving me week 53 instead of week 1. I saw another person's post on the same issue and dbDesigner's answer actually works:

[Get the week number from a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649720/get-the-week-number-from-a-given-date)

But this gives me 2016-01 in one column. I want two columns with one for correct week number and one for correct year to be able to do a sub query for my rolling YTD sales. For example for my first week 12/28/2015-1/3/2016, it will be week: 1 and year:2016

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand the solution you refer to? Because if you do, you should notice that year and week are concatinated. So you should undo concatination.

Comment: Well, thanks for the wake up. I separated them and they all worked.

Answer (score 0):

First, *none* of the week numbering methods in VBA follows the ISO 8601 standard.

Second, the week number of the week 2015-12-28 to 2016-01-03 is not the first of 2106 but 2015W53.

You can retrieve the correct ISO 8601 week number for any date with a function like this:

```
Public Function ISO_WeekYearNumber( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByRef intYear As Integer, _
  Optional ByRef bytWeek As Byte) _
  As String

' Calculates and returns year and week number for date datDate according to the ISO 8601:1988 standard.
' Optionally returns numeric year and week.
' 1998-2007, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.    Public Function ISO_WeekNumber( _
  ByVal datDate As Date) _
  As Byte

' Calculates and returns week number for date datDate according to the ISO 8601:1988 standard.
' 1998-2000, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' May be freely used and distributed.

  Const cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear  As Byte = 1
  Const cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear  As Byte = 53

  Dim bytWeek                   As Byte
  Dim bytISOThursday            As Byte
  Dim datLastDayOfYear          As Date

  bytWeek = DatePart("ww", datDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)

  If bytWeek = cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear Then
    bytISOThursday = Weekday(vbThursday, vbMonday)
    datLastDayOfYear = DateSerial(Year(datDate), 12, 31)
    If Weekday(datLastDayOfYear, vbMonday) >= bytISOThursday Then
      ' OK, week count of 53 is caused by leap year.
    Else
      ' Correct for Access97/2000 bug.
      bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear
    End If
  End If

  ISO_WeekNumber = bytWeek

End Function
' May be freely used and distributed.

  Const cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear  As Byte = 1
  Const cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear  As Byte = 53
  Const cbytMonthJanuary        As Byte = 1
  Const cbytMonthDecember       As Byte = 12
  Const cstrSeparatorYearWeek   As String = "W"

  Dim bytMonth                  As Byte
  Dim bytISOThursday            As Byte
  Dim datLastDayOfYear          As Date

  intYear = Year(datDate)
  bytMonth = Month(datDate)
  bytWeek = DatePart("ww", datDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)

  If bytWeek = cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear Then
    bytISOThursday = Weekday(vbThursday, vbMonday)
    datLastDayOfYear = DateSerial(intYear, cbytMonthDecember, 31)
    If Weekday(datLastDayOfYear, vbMonday) >= bytISOThursday Then
      ' OK, week count of 53 is caused by leap year.
    Else
      ' Correct for Access97/2000+ bug.
      bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear
    End If
  End If

  ' Adjust year where week number belongs to next or previous year.
  If bytMonth = cbytMonthJanuary Then
    If bytWeek >= cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear - 1 Then
      ' This is an early date of January belonging to the last week of the previous year.
      intYear = intYear - 1
    End If
  ElseIf bytMonth = cbytMonthDecember Then
    If bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear Then
      ' This is a late date of December belonging to the first week of the next year.
      intYear = intYear + 1
    End If
  End If

  ISO_WeekYearNumber = CStr(intYear) & cstrSeparatorYearWeek & Format(bytWeek, "00")

End Function
```

If you just need the week number itself, a function like this can be used:

Comment: Thanks, but I used the old post and it works fine now. I can get the correct week number and year number.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand the solution you refer to? 
Because if you do, you should notice that year and week are concatinated. 
So you should undo concatination.